# How to add Return to Site button or link in search site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, enterprise-search

I have a search center used by other web applications and site collections. When the users lands on the search site they make a couple of more searches or they go to search site home page by clicking the logo.

I need to place a link or a button that brings them back to the referring site. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the query string parameter as 'source' when you navigate to search center from source site cillection. Like https://scenter/page.aspx?source=encodedsitecollurl. Add a link in your search center page. Get the source parameter value using ootb js function GetUrlKeyVal('source') in search page and assign the value as href to anchor tag.